SparkSession can't connect to hive databases
I created a spark session like that:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession \
          .builder \
          .enableHiveSupport() \
          .getOrCreate()



But it can't connect with hive table. I checked sparkSession default in spark shell which can normal connect to hive. How can I config a sparksession to connect with hive like that?
Please help me and explain why my spark Session doesn't work.

maybe spark-shell has hive-site.xml,the pyspark run on your pc haven't hive-site.xml.in code ,you can try add "hive.metastore.uris" in your sparkConf can solve this,like this:
spark.conf.set("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://127.0.0.1:9083")


yeah, i tried it but it doesn't work for me :(

code and log detail maybe helpful
